# How to draw dots in the coordinates of slices in a d3 pie chart?

Tags: d3.js

I want to draw dot circle in each slice's endpoints. I have attached what I have drawn and what I want to do.
[image: current output]

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. the ans is:

```
            transform: function (d) {
                const x = radius * Math.sin(d.startAngle - Math.PI * 2);
                const y = radius * -Math.cos(d.startAngle - Math.PI * 2);

                    return "translate(" + x +","+ y + ")";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to compute the coordinates of a point ( relatively to the center of the piechart ) by percent ( 0 to 100 ) and piechart radius:

```
const getPoint = (radius, percent) => {
  const angle = percent / 100 * Math.PI * 2;
  const x = radius * Math.sin(angle);
  const y = radius * -Math.cos(angle);
  return {x, y};
}
```

Comment: can you please check again? still not getting the expected output. @Michael